# Angular2 ngFor Iterating over JSON

Tags: arrays, json, angular, ngfor

I´m fairly new to Angular2, and i want to read out a json file.
It´s working, that I get the file from a REST-Client, i can save the file in a local variable in a component and furthermore I´m able to read properties of the variable.
Now I´m trying to read other properties (Array) with ngFor, but this isn´t working.
Here´s the html:

```
//Working
<td>{{status.rights}}</td>
//Not working
<tr *ngFor="let folder of status.recfolders">
                                <td>{{folder.text}}</td>
                                <td>{{folder.size}}</td>
                                <td>{{folder.free}}</td>
                            </tr>
```

And the JSON:

```
{
  "status": {
    "rights": "full",
    "recfiles": "13",
    "recfolders": {
      "folder": [
        {
          "size": "7866296029184",
          "free": "3724003368960",
          "text": "\\\\edited\\Daten\\Videos\\Aufnahmen"
        },
        {
          "size": "59495149568",
          "free": "38696935424",
          "text": "C:\\Users\\edited\\Desktop"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If i try it that way, Angular says `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."`
If i try `*ngFor="let folder of status.recfolders.folder"` it´s not working either, but the error is `self.context.status.recfolders` is undefined...
I hope someone can say me, what I´m doing wrong ;)

Comment: You have to use Elvis operator to avoid `self.context` error : `*ngFor="let folder of status.recfolders?.folder"`

Comment: yes, that´s right, thank you!
The Elvis operator was the solution ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As folder contains array it should be there with **`*ngFor`**. `?.` operator will do the binding when folder array is available for the binding.

**NOTE**: `?.` operator should be used when you are working with *async call*. For *static data* it is not required.

It should be,

```
*ngFor="let folder of status.recfolders?.folder"
```

Comment: yes, that´s right, thank you!
The Elvis operator was the solution ;)

Comment: Can you edit the answer, so i can say it´s correct? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Elvis operator (?.)` to avoid `self.context` error.

Try this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let folder of status.recfolders?.folder">
      <td>{{folder.text}}</td>
      <td>{{folder.size}}</td>
      <td>{{folder.free}}</td>
</tr>
```